# Do I need a comma after "when in (%time)"?

Tags: punctuation, commas, when

> The company had just started to make money when in 1914 the World War put an end to its aspirations.

OR:

> The company had just started to make money when in 1914, the World War put an end to its aspirations

?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually neither.  It should be:

> The company had just started to make money when, in 1914, the World War put an end to its aspirations.

The reason being that "in 1914" is supplemental information, a parenthetical comment.  The sentence would read just fine without the extra info.

--- Update to add ---
To summarize the (rather lengthy) comments below, this [Guide to Punctuation](http://www.informatics.sussex.ac.uk/department/docs/punctuation/node13.html#SECTION00044000000000000000) suggests that bracketing commas can sometimes be omitted.  I prefer them in this instance, but I can't really argue with those who feel it reads okay without them.

However, as the guide says, you do need *both* the bracketing commas.  Having just the one at the end would be incorrect.

Comment: The phrase "in 1914" is short enough that it doesn't *need* commas.

Comment: @Chan-HoSuh You're right. However, in that case, a comma may be justified after *1914*: "The company had just started to make money when in 1914, the World War put an end to its aspirations." There are really two independent statements joined by *when* here.

Comment: @Chan-HoSuh - I suppose you could legitimately omit them, but I prefer it with the commas.

Comment: @Chan-HoSuh - Disagree. Often in the beginning or at the end of a sentence or clause, a short parenthetical phrase or clause can skip commas. Here the parenthetical phrase breaks up the clause "when the World War . . . ." The flow is interrupted, and the commas are needed to reflect that.

Comment: I agree with Lynn and bib, partly because you would naturally pause to insert "in 1914" if speaking this sentence.

Comment: @Kris: I disagree. Obviously, *"in 1914"* is a parenthetical clause. As Chan-Ho Suh says, because it's so short you can get away with omitting the "enclosing" commas. But it's both or neither - you can't keep one and discard the other.

Comment: @Chan-HoSuh could you post a reference to the rule that if the parenthetical clause is small enough you can omit the comas? I am not doubting you, I have just never heard of this.

Comment: @terdon According to Larry Trask's [Guide to Punctuation](http://www.informatics.sussex.ac.uk/department/docs/punctuation/node13.html#SECTION00044000000000000000), the kind of commas under discussion ("bracketing commas") are for "weak interruptions", and "In many cases a weak interruption does not absolutely require bracketing commas."

Comment: @FumbleFingers The reasons for dropping the comma-pair and inserting a comma are different and in no way related.

Comment: @Kris: I know that. But I still disagree with your first comment saying the sentence would be validly punctuated with just a single comma after *1914*. I'm not big on punctuation rules, but imho that single comma would never be acceptable in this context.

Comment: @Chan-HoSuh and everyone:  I have updated the answer based on the comment discussion.